# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to use delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, mapkit

I'm trying to implement same logic for different tabs in iOS application, but get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode 0x0). It's a simple application that should allow user to mark some points on the map(right now with annotations), and draws lines between them in process.

Class that contains logic:

```
class MapController : NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate{

    var Map: MKMapView!

    var points : [CGPoint]

    init(_Map : MKMapView!, delClass : String)//, coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        self.Map = _Map
        points = [CGPoint]()

        self.Map.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite


        let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.0000000,
                                            longitude: 49.0000000)

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10.01,
                                    longitudeDelta: 10.01)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centre, span: span)
        self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        self.Map.regionThatFits(region)


        let urlTemplate = "http://someip/mapcache/tms/1.0.0/test@GoogleMapsCompatible/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"

        let carte_indice = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: urlTemplate)

        carte_indice.geometryFlipped = true

        carte_indice.canReplaceMapContent = false
        print("Map")
        self.Map.addOverlay(carte_indice)
    }


    func longPressGesture()
    {
        let lpg = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self.Map, action: "longPressAction:")
        lpg.minimumPressDuration = 1;
        Map.addGestureRecognizer(lpg)
    }

    func longPressAction(myRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let currPoint = myRecognizer.locationInView(Map)
        let point = Map.convertPoint(currPoint, toCoordinateFromView: Map)
        points.append(currPoint);
        if(points.count>1)
        {
            let startPoint = Map.convertPoint(points[points.count-2], toCoordinateFromView: Map)
            let endPoint = Map.convertPoint(currPoint, toCoordinateFromView: Map)
            var lineCoords = [startPoint,endPoint]
            var line = MKPolyline(coordinates: &lineCoords, count: 2)
            var test = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: line)
            test.lineWidth = 10;
            test.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            Map.addOverlay(line)
        }
        let myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation();
        myAnnotation.coordinate = point
        myAnnotation.title = "Test"
        myAnnotation.subtitle = "Test subtitle"
        Map.addAnnotation(myAnnotation);
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay);
            circle.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor();
            circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1);
            circle.lineWidth = 1;
            return circle;
        }else  if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
            var carte_Renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            carte_Renderer.alpha = 0.9
            return carte_Renderer
        }else if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay);
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor();
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5;
            return polylineRenderer;
        }else {
            return MKPolylineRenderer();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController classes look like this:

```
class BuildTrack: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  MKMapViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var testRef: MKMapView!

var mapController : MapController!


required init?(coder aDecoder : NSCoder)
{

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapController = MapController(_Map: testRef, delClass: "BuildTrack")

    mapController.longPressGesture();
            testRef.delegate = mapController

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I guess it's because i don't declare a delegate right. I tried to do this in my MapController class like this:

```
self.Map = _Map
Map.delegate = BuildTrack.self()
```

, but got same exception when i clicked map(now i don't even see the map, it crashes in the init of MapController), looks like something gets disposed before time.

Is the problem really in delegates, and is this approach ok? When i had one ViewController and all logic was inside it, it worked fine, problem occurred when i tried to separate logic from interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see problem in using outlet `testRef` before it have value

Try to add `!` in `mapController` declaration

```
var mapController: MapController!
```

and remove `mapController` initialization from init:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: i moved initialization to viewDidLoad, not it gives me error "Use of local variable mapController before it's declaration"

Comment: @Jamil remove var keyword making mapController in viewDidLoad

Comment: new to swift, always think that compiler messages me if i try to declare variable with the same name
yes, it worked, but now i get same error in AppDelegate when i click on the map

Comment: Ok. Just stop use MapController class: delete it and move all code to BuildTrack. Because BuildTrack is delegate of MapView, but seems like you think that MapController is delegate, and it is not

Comment: I want to pass MapController delegate of MapView of the current tab and call MapController's methods, is that possible?

Comment: make MapController delegate of MapView and set testRef.delegate = mapController in last line of viewDidLoad

Comment: I re-wrote declaration of MapController like this:
class MapController : NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate{
, but in BuildTrack i can't write testRef.delegate = MapController, and testRef.delegate = MapController.self also gives me error

Comment: When i try to testRef.delegate = MapController, it gives me Can't assign value of type MapController.Type to type MKMapViewDelegate,
and self() wants additional parameters

Comment: do you realize difference between MapController and mapController?

Comment: my bad. yes, now it compiles, but i get same error in the AppDelegate

Comment: @Jamil in `longPressGesture` function delete `.Map` after `self`: replace `target: self.Map` with `target: self`

Comment: Actually, i didn't get why i should delegate of MapController class, i thought it should be reverse